# Rails 4 I18n-js gem not picking up changes to the locale files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-i18n

I recently installed the i18n-js gem to enable translations in javascript but any changes I make to the locale file are not flowing through to my javascript.

assets/javascripts/application.js

```
//= require i18n
//= require i18n/translations
//= require_tree .
```

config/locales/en.yml

```
en:
  confirmation: "Confirmation"
  yes: "Yes"
  no: "Cancel"
```

Gemfile

```
# Internationalization in javascript
gem 'i18n-js', '~> 2.1.2'
```

assets/javascripts/config.coffee

```
$ ->
  alert I18n.t('yes')
  dataConfirmModal.setDefaults
      title: I18n.t("confirmation");
      commit: I18n.t("yes");
      cancel: I18n.t("no");
```

The yes/no translations do not flow through but the confirmation one does. I have tried everything from restarting the server to running `I18n.backend.reload!` when the locales files change.

Comment: I encounter the exact same problem and it's just occurred only for this specific word. I end up prefix yes/no with something else. In the end I just don't know what's going on.

Comment: Do you guys have multiple locales files? In my case i always need to update them in the twin files as well (copy paste it is enough)

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried running `rake tmp:cache:clear` and `rake i18n:js:export` from Terminal?  If not, please try that.  Seems to fix things for me when I experience this problem.

Comment: `rake i18n:js:export` fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

This is a general Rails issue, not just i18n-js, you can see this if you look up :yes or :no from the console:

```
> I18n.t(:yes)
=> "translation missing: en.yes"
```

There's an [article talking about this](https://juliankniephoff.wordpress.com/2012/09/01/reserved-words-in-yaml-and-translating-booleans-in-rails/). TL;DR, these are reserved words meaning true and false, and you can redefine these in your YAML as:

```
"yes": "Yes"
```